# Processing - On button press do X for 3 sec - ignore further button presses

Tags: javascript, timer, processing

I have a processing script that has Arduino inputs.

On a button press I have an element that 'grows' and ellipse for 3 secs then returns to normal.

What I can't seem to work out is how to ignore further button presses within those 3 seconds.

Here's the simplified code.

```
int savedTime;
int growTime = 3000;

void setup() {
    //Start counting milliseconds
    savedTime = millis();
}

void draw() {
    if (arduino.digitalRead(2) == Arduino.HIGH){
        //Starts Timer for 'Grow' animation
        savedTime = millis();
    }

    int passedTime = millis() - savedTime;

    if (passedTime >= growTime) {
        opacity = 10;
        if (circleSize > 0){
            scale(circleSize);
            noStroke();
            circleSize -= 0.0009;
        }
    }else{
        scale(circleSize);
        noStroke();
        circleSize += 0.0003;
        opacity = 70;
    }
    ellipse(0, 0, circleSize, circleSize);
}
```

I understand that my current code checks to see when the last button press happened and effectively if I kept pressing the button the 'grow' effect will keep firing.

How to I make it so if the 'grow' effect is happening, further button presses are ignored?

I hope this makes sense and I've included what people need to understand. it's part of a larger script so excuse me if I've missed something vital!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store in some way that you are already in the middle of processing your last input so further clicks will be ignored.

I would go with a separate boolean variable like **processing**, or something like that and check that you are not processing before updating your last savedTime.
You could go also without any additional variable playing with invalid values on savedTime, but I think with an extra variable everything would be much clear.

```
bool processing = false;
int savedTime;
int growTime = 3000;

void setup() {
    //Start counting milliseconds
    savedTime = millis();
}

void draw() {
    if (!processing && arduino.digitalRead(2) == Arduino.HIGH){
        //Starts Timer for 'Grow' animation
        savedTime = millis();
        processing = true;
    }

    int passedTime = millis() - savedTime;

    if (passedTime >= growTime) {
        opacity = 10;
        if (circleSize > 0){
            scale(circleSize);
            noStroke();
            circleSize -= 0.0009;
        } else {
            processing = false;
        }
    }else{
        scale(circleSize);
        noStroke();
        circleSize += 0.0003;
        opacity = 70;
    }
    ellipse(0, 0, circleSize, circleSize);
}
```

Didn't try the code, so maybe some syntax mistakes. Hope it helps!

Edit: I assumed you don't want to process any other input until the ellipse has completely decreased, if you want to process new inputs just after the 3 seconds "growing", you might want to move the `processing = false;` statement to outside the else block I added.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah a few syntax changes but you cracked it. I had a feeling it would be something like that, but I'm new to this and been staring at it for too long! Thanks again.